# Jquery refresh php and stop function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a problem. I'm refreshing a div:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false }); 
        setInterval(function() {
            $('#refresh').load('call.php');
        }, 3000);
    });
    //-->
</script>

<div id="refresh"></div>
```

call.php:

```
<?php $say = 0; ?>
```

Everything ok now. in `javascript` if `$say=1`, i want stop refreshing div and open a popup and `echo $say;` , `if $say=0`, i want continue  refresh div. but can't do this. can someone hep me ?

edit:
i'm already get variable ( $say ) with

```
var say="<?php echo $say; ?>";
```

(in the same page)

i have a new problem... 
codes:

```
    var theRefresh = setInterval(function() {
        $('#refresh').load('call.php');


        checkValue();
    }, 3000);

     function checkValue(){
             var sayi = <?php echo $say; ?>;
        if(sayi==1){

           clearInterval(theRefresh);

        }

     }

});

//--></script>
```

in call.php:

```
<?php 


$say=1;

 ?>
```

but javascript does not get `$say` from call.php. 
i want get value from call.php file to javascript 
thanks..

Comment: use clearinterval, google it.

Comment: You have to output `$say` in `call.php` to get the content with `load()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make a function that checks the value in the #refresh div.  Assuming you are actually echoing the $say value into that div.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false }); 

    var theRefresh = setInterval(function() {
        $('#refresh').load('call.php');
        checkValue();
    }, 3000);

     function checkValue(){
        var say = $('#refresh').html();
        if(say==1){
           clearInterval(theRefresh);
        }
     }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use https://code.google.com/p/jquery-timer/

*Code is untested*

First correct your php to output something:

```
<?php echo $say = 0; ?>
```

Then:

```
var timer = $.timer(function() {
    refresh();
}, 3000, true);

function refresh()
{
    $.ajax({
      url: "call.php",
      cache: false
    })
      .done(function( html ) {
        if(html == "1")
        {   
            timer.pause();      
            // here pop up code
            alert(html); 

        }
        else
        {
         $('#refresh').html(html);
         timer.play();
        }
    });
}
```